# Python search multiple values exists in list of lists

Tags: python

I want to give an example directly to explain better

```
search1 = 'test'
search2 = 'value'

search_array = [[], [], [], [], ....]
```

I have a list of lists with different lengths and values. I want to find index number of a list if both search1 and search2 exists. At the moment i'm doing nested loops which is super slow performance wise with 50.000 items in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change data structure, you could use list of sets, so time complexity of search becomes O(N) instead of O(N * M):

```py
search1 = 'test'
search2 = 'value'

search_array = [set(), set(), set(), set(), ....]
```

And to find indices you need `in` operator and one loop:

```
indices = [i for (i, s) in enumerate(search_array) if search1 in s and search2 in s]
```